# Unsure if I should post an answer

Tags: discussion

I came across a question today and I am not sure whether I should be answer such a question. Ethically it bothers me but on the other hand it may help a future stackoverflow user as well. For example, someone who is a systems administrator and is in a fix?

The thread I am referring to is

[Close an Adobe Acrobat file opened by another user on different computer (same network)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752920/close-an-adobe-acrobat-file-opened-by-another-user-on-different-computer-same-n)

Would the community be kind enough to suggest the course of action?

Comment: You'll have to decide this for yourself.  I personally think closing files on other people's computers is ill-advised and bad design, but I did write something into a product once so that nightly updates would automatically force-close an application so that it could be updated, so there might be legitimate use cases.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: This particular question involves neither malware nor viruses.

Comment: I agree @RobertHarvey. This user may be genuine but the answer can be easily accessed by so many people. A simple search in google will land them up on this page and then it can be used in a malicious way

Comment: I would personally say that it would depend on the answer you're proposing (I think I have a pretty good idea).  For example, I wouldn't post an answer recommending a denial of service attack to take down the machine.  If it's a supported part of the language or eco-system, that's an entirely different story.

Comment: No, it doesn't, but it *does* involve answering with material that you think could be misused.

Comment: Thanks @Comintern. I think I agree with what you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, you're not responsible for the manner in which people use the information you give them.  It's not your fault if they take your answer and use it to write a `DestroyBaghdad()` procedure.

That said, it is [Stack Exchange's policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal) to disallow harmful material in the general case.  If someone is asking you to help them defeat the security of a specific website somewhere, your choice should be clear: *refrain from doing so.*

Comment: Thanks Rob. Makes my life easier. I will go ahead and post it... BTW LOL@DestroyBaghdad()

Comment: But Robert, there's a pesky site that injects garbage text whenever I use the reader mode to read the articles and I need help to create an userscript that will remove them :(.